# My android app doesn't work on android 7.0 devices

Tags: android-studio

My app works fine while using the Android Studio Emulator.
I have a problem running it on real devices.
It works on Android 7.1.2 but doesn't work on Android 7.0

I tried to change the "CompileSdkVersion" from 26 to 24.

What changes should I do in my Build.gradle file to fix this problem?

Code:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.roomit.yonatan.projectx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.6"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.+'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: "Unfortunately, App has stopped"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)